# Does oxydation contribute to the acidicity of raw pressed apple juice?

Tags: mashing, oxidation

When mashing apples with a rotary masher, the mash and juice gets quite oxygenated.

Does this contribute to the acidicity of the raw apple juice?

Comment: Oxides are not acidic by nature, as far as i know. Any reason you ask? Any experience that would say there is a connection? Or just "better safe than sorry"?

Comment: @Molot when making apple juice it has always felt like the less the apple juice is oxygenated, the less acidic it tastes. This however is a flimsy theory, which I am testing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oxidation has the opposite affect. It creates hydroxides.

What oxidation will do however is impart a candyish jolly rancher like flavor which I personally find distasteful.

A typical and well characterized example of what this ends up tasting like is comparing a good strawberry wine or watermelon wine with those that have oxidized. Good wines of these two taste like the fruit, oxidized ones taste like those jelly filled strawberry candies (for strawberry) or jolly rancher candy (for the watermelon) and it's disgusting in a wine.

That's why we use ascorbic and/or citric acids when preparing fruit, it greatly inhibits and reduces oxidation of the fruit.